# Draw isometric map based on heightmap

Tags: draw, game-engine, isometric

I am not able to get my head arround my problem triyng for two days now. The highly rated answer on stackoverflow did not help me. I am remaking an game which uses an isometric view. I generated a 2D heightmap matrix that i now want to draw using different tiles. Should the numbers in the array represent the edges or tiles? How to i iterate over my array? I am stuck.

[image: tiles]

These are the tiles to simulate height, they have different sizes.

Comment: Your array should represent the vertices (points...) if you want to acheive the image you included. Then you simply iterate across and over, generating triangles as you go and draw these.

Comment: Both ways work, and it depends on your interpretation of the height data which one you'd use. "How to i iterate over my array?" ... the usual way?? Iterate for what? To correctly draw a square isometric map, you'd start with the corner that ends up at the top of your screen, then go down in diagonals. "Row" (or "column", depending on your map orientation) wise, top to bottom, also works.

Comment: thx for your input guys, i think the problem is clearer now to me. gonna post updates and accept your answer as soon as i solve the problem